# How to use structs, pointers and a function in C?

Tags: c

I have learned how to use functions and structs and pointers. I want to combined them all into one. But the code that I write doesn't seem to work. The compiler tells me the test is an undeclared identifier. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct character 
{
  int *power;
};

void test (use_power)

int main ()
{
  test (use_power)
  printf("%d\n",*power);

  return 0;
}

void test () 
{
  int use_power = 25;
  struct character a;
  a.power = &use_power;
}
```

Comment: What is this code?, it's completely wrong, it's wrong in many ways and it's just a little of code.

Comment: "The compiler tells me the test is an undeclared identifier."... That's all it tells you?

Comment: @DigitalNinja It has to stop at the *first* error, all the program is an error.

Comment: @DigitalNinja yes.

Comment: @iharob I know the code is wrong that's why I'm asking for help. You guys are literally the only resource that I have!

Comment: Right, it's not getting past the first... My point is there are many errors.

Comment: @DigitalNinja I know many there are many errors. I want to learn, please help me understand what I'm doing wrong! I have a basic understanding of all of these separate topics. Combining them together is the difficult part.

Comment: What do you think the line `void test use_power()` is doing?  One of `test` and `use_power` is an interloper (probably `use_power`, for all the compiler mentions `test`), and there's a semicolon missing too.  Continue from there, one error message at a time.  If you must ask about compiler error messages, then please include them in the question — at least, include the first one; the others may be consequences of the first.  Up to about 5 error messages would be OK; more than that is too many.  Include the file names for the error messages, but leave out long paths so that they're readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems to be wrong. Your definition for `test` contains no arguments as

```
void test () 
{
  int use_power = 25;
  struct character a;
  a.power = &use_power;
}
```

but your prototype contains one argument

```
void test (use_power)
```

which is wrongly put. First there are no semicolons`;` at the end of your prototype declaration, secondly by looking at your code, `use_power` is a variable and not a datatype so it cannot be present solely in a function declaration.

You will get an argument mismatch error.

You have used the line in `main()`

```
printf("%d\n",*power);
```

which is absolutely wrong. you cannot access any member of a structure without a structure variable.

And again, you have not mentioned the`;` after your call to the incorrect `test()`before this line

As you have not put your question so properly, I must figure out what you wish to achieve. I bet you want to hold the address of a integer in the pointer member of a structure and then print its value.

Below is a code snippet which will work as you desire.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct character 
{
  int *power;
};
struct character a;    //define a structure variable

void test ();

int main ()
{
  test ();
  printf("%d\n",*(a.power)); // print the member of structure variable a 

  return 0; 
}

void test () 
{
  int use_power = 25;
  a.power = &use_power;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This is EXACTLY what I was looking for! Thanks again!

Comment: I didn't know I could do that. I would have done so early if I had known!

Comment: @BLUEPIXY did you compile?

Comment: It does not matter whether you did compile.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY ok fine. Can i know what kind of undefined behavior? I couldn't get it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111862/discussion-between-anish-sharma-and-bluepixy).

Answer (score 1):

Your code has many mistakes it can't even compile

1. Multiple missing semicolons.
2. Implicit declaration of `test()` here

   ```
   test (use_power)
   ```

   with a missing semicolon too.
3. `power` is not declared in `main()`.
4. This line

   ```
   void test use_power()
   ```

   does not make sense and is invalid, and also has no semicolon.
5. The `a` instance in `test()` defined at the end is local to `test()` and as such will be deallocated when `test()` returns. The `use_power` `int`, has exactly the same problem and trying to extract it's address from the function is useless because you can't access it after the function has returned.

I have no idea what you were trying to do, but this might be?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct character {
    int *power;
};

/* Decalre the function here, before calling it
 * or perhaps move the definition here
 */
void test(struct character *pointer);
/*                                  ^ please */

int
main(void) /* int main() is not really a valid signature */
{
    struct character instance;
    test(&instance);
    if (instance.power == NULL)
        return -1;
    printf("%d\n", *instance.power);
    free(instance.power);
    return 0;
}

void
test(struct character *pointer)
{
    pointer->power = malloc(sizeof(*pointer->power));
    if (pointer->power != NULL)
        *pointer->power = 25;
}
```

Comment: test is the name of a function.  I think he meant to forward declare a function called test that takes a parameter called use_power.  Unfortunately when he actually defines test it doesn't take a parameter but it does modify the non existent use_power parameter.  Or maybe I have that wrong - its hard to tell.

Comment: I think maybe the answer is to delete this line altogether: `void test use_power()` and remove the use_power parameter from the test function call in main.  Then at least it makes sense.

Comment: ok... But can't you use pointers to get values outside of the scope of void  test? I'm trying to to declare a pointer in struct. Use that pointer in a function. And then print that result in the main function.

Comment: No, because they have automatic storage and will be deleted after the function has returned, you can use `static` which would give it `static` storage, but it's highly unlikely that you **want** that.

Comment: @iharob yes, the code you wrote is what I was trying to do. Thank you so much! Now I can analyze it and figure out the rest. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

example

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct character {
    int *power;
};

void test(struct character *var);

int main (void){
    struct character use_power;
    int power = 5;

    use_power.power = &power;
    test(&use_power);
    printf("%d\n", power);

    return 0;
}

void test(struct character *var){
    int use_power = *var->power;
    *var->power = use_power * use_power;
}
```